# Quotient by a topological groupoid.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, quotient-spaces, groupoids, lie-groupoids

Let $G$ be a group acting on a topological space $X$, then the quotient map $X \to X/G$ is open.

I want to ask, whether this fact generalizes to orbit spaces of groupoids. More precisely:

Let $G$ be a topological groupoid. I will denote objects by $G_0$, morphisms by $G_1$, the source map by $s$ and the target map by $t$.

There is an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $G_0$:

$$x\sim y \text{ iff. there exists a morphism } g \in G_1 \text{ such that } s(g) = x \text{ and } t(g) = y.$$

It is easy to check that this is an equivalence relation. The class corresponding to $x$ will be called its orbit. Note that, the orbit of $x$ contains all those points in $G_0$ which are targets of morphisms originating at $x$, or in other words, the orbit of $x$ is the set $t(s^{-1}(x))$.

Then, $G_0/\sim$ equipped with the quotient topology
is called the orbit space of the groupoid $G$.

My question is: is the quotient map $G_0 \to G_0/\sim$ open?

*Remark*. We can recover the original statement about quotient by a group, by considering the *translation gropoid* $G \ltimes X$ (since its orbit space is precisely $X/G$).

---

I haven't made any progress in the general case.

EDIT: I was making things unnecessarily complicated. At least, for the étale case, the proof is laughably trivial; its just a point-set argument similar to what we do in the group case.

First of note that if $p : X \to X/\sim$ is a quotient map and $A\subset X$, then $p^{-1}(p(A))$ is the set of all the elements of $X$ which are related by $\sim $ to some element in $A$.

Now, let $G$ be an étale topological groupoid with orbit space $G_0/\sim$ and quotient map $q : G_0 \to G_0/\sim$. Suppose $U$ is an open subset of $G_0$. We need to show that $q(U)$ is open. It suffices to show that $q^{-1}(q(U))$ is open because $q$ is a quotient map. By the preceding observation, $q^{-1}(q(U))$  is the set of those elements $G_0$ which are in the orbit of some element $U$, or in other words, it is the set of all points in $G_0$ which are targets of morphisms originating in $U$. Thus, $q^{-1}(q(U)) = t(s^{-1}(U))$, which is open because both $s$ and $t$ are local homeomorphism.

So, that does it for the étale case.

Comment: @Mummy_the_turkey Sure. So, if $U$ is open in $G_0$. Then, is it true that, $q^{-1}(q(U)) = ts^{-1}(U)$. If so, then it seems we're done (at least in the étale case).

Comment: I am very sorry, in a fit of temporary insanity I imagined that all quotient maps are open which is, of course, wrong

Comment: @Mummy_the_turkey Yes, not all quotient maps are open (otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question). But what you wrote was correct: if $q : X \to X/\sim$ is the quotient map then $q^{-1}(U)$ is open iff. $U$ is open.

Comment: If $q^{-1}(q(U)) = ts^{-1}(U)$, which is open, since, $s$ is continuous and $t$ is an open map. Then, this means that $q^{-1}(q(U))$ is open and hence $q(U)$ is open. I just want to make sure that $q^{-1}(q(U)) = ts^{-1}(U)$ is indeed true.

Comment: You are correct, what I wrote was not wrong, I was simply apologising that it was unhelpful. Since I am incredibly far from a specialist in this area, the best I can say is that if $\tilde{t}$ exists and your diagram commutes then you are correct. However I think you already know this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in the proof above, étale requirement is an overkill, since all we ever used was that $t$ is open. So, we actually proved the result for the groupoids which have target map open. [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+groupoid) calls such groupoids, *open topological groupoids*. (Note that if the target map is open, then so is the source one).

In particular, the statement is always true for Lie groupoids.

---

Now, coming to the general case: **the assertion is false**.

The point is, any equivalence relation on a topological space $X$ can be realized as a topological groupoid (as described in [*'Topological groupoids quantales'*](http://www.appliedlogictudelft.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/A-Palmigiano_R-Re_Topological-Groupoid-Quantales_Applied-Logic-TU-Delft.pdf) by Palmigiano and Re). That is to say, if $R \subset X\times X$ is an equivalence relation, then, $R$ can be though of as a groupoid over $X$, with the projection maps (restricted to $R$) as the source and the target maps. The orbit space of this groupoid, $X/\sim$ is precisely the quotient space $X/R$.

So, if $R$ was a *non-open* relation (*ie.*, the quotient map $X \to X/R$ is not open). Then if we think of $R$ as a groupoid over $X$, then the quotient map $X \to X/\sim$ is not open. For example consider the quotient space $[0, 1]/(0\sim 1)$. We know that the associated quotient map is not open. Thus, the quotient map for the orbit space of the associated groupoid is not open.